# Regex pattern to get the number bofre the searched query and a flag with new lines?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have this string:

```
-wordpagefound: 1 offerte 201135455 fam. gaudino, umbau wohnung, winterthur seite 3 von 17
rektifikat
projekt 7514505

pos.nr menge uberschrift artikelnummer richtpreis betrag
me bild artikelbeschreibung exkl. mwst exkl. mwst

dusche - wc eltern
```

How can I get the number right after `-wordpagefound:` if I search for "wc"?
I need to get the page where it is found including new lines (for OCR purpose).

I tried to do this `preg_match_all('/(-wordpagefound).*([0-9]).*('.$searchText.')/mi', $file->text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)`  but apparently because of the new lines it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your current code? What is the problem? What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I tried to do this ````preg_match_all('/(-wordpagefound).*([0-9]).*('.$searchText.')/mi', $file->text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)```` but apparently because of the new lines it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Please update the question with these details.

Comment: Sorry for missing it, the expected output would be the page number where the $searchText variable is found. The logis is simple, any word you search is always preceded with the flag -wordpagefound: and the number of the page which I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/-wordpagefound\D*(\d+).*?\bwc\b/si
/-wordpagefound\D*\K\d+(?=.*?\bwc\b)/si
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dw87le/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/Dw87le/2).

*Details*:

- `-wordpagefound` - a fixed string
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\bwc\b` - a whole word `wc`.

The second regex is a variation of the first regex where `\K` discards all text matched so far and the right regex part is enclosed into a positive lookahead to check for the pattern presence but exclude from match.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you for your amazing answer and solution.. Apparently it works just fine as you mentioned, but just one more clarification please. What if instead of "wc" we need to put "off" (where the whole word is "offerten") how can I do this in this case where I only search off instead of offerten?

Comment: @DuliNini If the `off` is not a whole word, but the word start, remove the last `\b`. `preg_match('/-wordpagefound\D*(\d+).*?\b' . $searchText . '/si', $text, $matches)`. Remove the word boundaries if you do not care if it is a whole word or not.

Comment: Thousands of thanks Wiktor.
I selected your answer as a final solution. Best regards!